# How to send gps data using sim900 gps module and arduino uno?

Tags: gps, arduino, tracking, sim900

I have one gps GSM SIM900 and arduino and my project is to track vehicle using this. When gps take data then i need GSM sim 900 to activate the gps and the the data to database or google spreadsheet.

If anyone have done same kind of project using arduino uno sim900 and gps module plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think SIM900 has gprs in it. you will have to use a separate gprs shield/module for that purpose.

Comment: what do you mean by "activating the gps"?